# Java Object uniq value

Tags: java, class, object, abstract

I have this abstract class :

```
public abstract class Pile {

    protected Deck d=new Deck(); 

    public Pile(){

    }
    public abstract void PrintCard();
    public abstract boolean IsEmpty();
}
```

I want the `d` field and its value to be the same for all objects of type `Pile` (and its subclasses).

I want this to happen because I remove cards and add them do the deck so it has to be only one deck.

Comment: ...make it `static`? Or inject the `Deck` as a parameter of `Pile`.

Comment: if i make it static it wont create another deck on new object? i cant add object i have to many different subclasses to give it like this thanx

Comment: No, it won't. However, each instance of `Pile` will be using the same `Deck`, which may not necessarily be a good thing. Think about it; you have a room full of different groups of people playing a multitude of card games. Does each group have its own `Deck`, or do all of the groups draw from a single `Deck` placed on a table in the middle of the room?

Comment: @ΓιώργοςΦιωτάκης what do you think `static` does? Maybe read up about it.

Comment: Static means that d will always be that deck. You cannot change the value of d once you set it.

Comment: @blahfunk "You cannot change the value of d once you set it" that's `final`.

Comment: @Andy final means that you cannot redefine this in children.

Comment: @blahfunk `final` prevents you creating a static variable of the same name in a subclass *and* it prevents you from changing the value of the variable. However, nothing stops a subclass changing the value of a protected, static, *non-final* field.

Comment: @Andy I need to go back to school. Yes, static just means that it is a non object. It is shared by all decedents and only "initialized" at the start of execution and belongs to the class, not to any specific object. I apologize for the confusion I may have caused here.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is simply to make `d` `static` (it's also worth making it `final`, so that no subclass can replace it with a different instance):

```
public abstract class Pile {
  protected static final Deck d=new Deck(); 

  public abstract void PrintCard();
  public abstract boolean IsEmpty();
}
```

However, static variables like this can be problematic, especially from a testing perspective. It is also tricky to change later if you need some `Pile`s to have one `Deck` whilst others have a different `Deck` (e.g. JonK's example).

You can alternatively inject the `Deck` as a parameter:

```
public abstract class Pile {
  protected final Deck d;

  public Pile(Deck d) {
    this.d = d;
  }

  public abstract void PrintCard();
  public abstract boolean IsEmpty();
}
```

You can now inject a value of your choosing (e.g. a mock) when you construct the `Pile`. The second solution is the one I would choose.

Comment: Second is a much better solution.

Comment: The second solution here not only is easier to work with but it also allows to KISS (keep it simple, stupid)

Comment: i need to change the deck so i cant make it final , i thought your second solution to but i have 4 different piles with 3 objects needed each one of them so it is not so easy to insert a deck like this, basically one sec can my deck class contains an array of different card and i have some methods to delete and add cards if i make deck final will i be able to call them?

Comment: Making the variable `final` means that you can't reassign `d`, i.e. `Pile.d = new Deck()` will be a compiler error; you can still call methods on `d` which might change it, e.g. `d.addCard()`. If you need multiple `Pile`s to share a single deck, you should keep it final, so that no `Pile` can arbitrarily change its `Deck`.

Comment: my point is final will protect only the value or and its contains?